# Is there any way to create a System Tray Icon in Java on Ubuntu?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a System Tray Icon on Ubuntu, I used the same code I did on Windows and it works no problem on there but on Ubuntu, I can't get it to work.

I've tried re-working the code to come up with a working method but I have had no luck.

Here is my Code:

```
private static TrayIcon trayIcon;

public ProgramTray()
{
    showTrayIcon();
}

private static void showTrayIcon()
{
    trayIcon = new TrayIcon(createIcon("/app/Icon.png", "Tray Icon"));
    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    try 
    {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } 

    catch (AWTException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(ProgramTray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

protected static Image createIcon(String path, String desc)
{
    URL imageURL = ProgramTray.class.getResource(path);
    return (new ImageIcon(imageURL, desc)).getImage();
}
```

When this is executed it always throws an UnsupportedOperationException. I'm open to any solutions as to how to get this to work.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can provide so that we can see just where this error is coming from?

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(TrayIcon.java:144)
 at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(TrayIcon.java:168)
 at app.ProgramTray.showTrayIcon(ProgramTray.java:23)
 at app.ProgramTray.<init>(ProgramTray.java:18)
 at app.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:16)
 at app.GUI.lambda$main$0(GUI.java:59)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The system tray is not supported on the current platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440268/the-system-tray-is-not-supported-on-the-current-platform)