# AWT and Ubuntu 20 -> The system tray is not supported on the current platform

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, awt

I am trying to run [this solution](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a) (AWT System Tray to control a JavaFX application) on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I tried with openjdk 14 and 17, result is the same:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The system tray is not supported on the current platform.
    at java.desktop/java.awt.SystemTray.getSystemTray(SystemTray.java:188)
    at com.foo.fxtest1.JavaFxTest5.addAppToTray(JavaFxTest5.java:119)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Trying to solve the problem I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574518/5057736): saying that `Gnome 3.28 (used in Ubuntu 18.04) removed the System tray`. I thought, that Ubuntu 20 didn't have a system tray, and that was the problem. However, in the top right corner of my screen I see the following:

[image].

As you see there are three application icons - Telegram, Viber and Alarm clock. As I understand these icons are shown in system tray, so
system tray exists. Then what is the problem? Doesn't AWT support Ubuntu 20 system tray? Could anyone explain?

Comment: I created the solution you linked, but I only tested it on Windows a long time ago.  I do not use Ubuntu, so cannot assist you with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in JDK. Issue is [here](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8289233).